# Creating matplotlib widget callback inside a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback

I am using python 2.7 on Windows.
I have a function which creates a figure with a CheckButtons widget, and it also includes the definition of the button's callback. When I call the function once, everything is OK, but when I call it more than once, the buttons stops responding, as follows:

- If the figure is created using `plt.subplots()`, none of the buttons respond.
- If the figure was created using `plt.figure()`, the behavior is inconsistent; sometimes only the 1st created button responds, and sometimes both respond.

My guess is that is has to do with the scope of the callback, but I couldn't pinpoint the problem using trial-and-error.

Sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons

def create_button():
    plt.subplots() # or: plt.figure()
    rax = plt.axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
    check = CheckButtons(rax, ['on'], [True])
    def callback(label):
        check.labels[0].set_text('on' if check.lines[0][0].get_visible() else 'off')
        plt.draw()
    check.on_clicked(callback)

create_button()
#create_button() # uncomment to reproduce problem
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the `CheckButtons` instance created inside the function no longer exists after the function returns.

The solution I came up with was to keep a list in the scope where the function is called (I used a static variable in a class), and append the instance to this list from within the function. This way the `CheckButtons` instance still exists when the function exits. In order for that list to not grow more than needed, I also wrote a function which deletes the corresponding instance from the list, and registered this function as a callback for the event of the figure being closed by the user.

I will be happy to hear comments on my solution, or suggestions for more Pythonish solution, if such a solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think also if you `return check` at the end of the function this will work to keep the button alive on exit.